# IPTABLES and GEOIP: Show Custom Webpage to Blocked Visitors

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, geolocation, geoip

Because of legal protection, as a first stage of launching my project I will focus on couple of countries only. The number of supported countries will grow.

I know, it is possible to block or allow whole countries through iptables and geoip. However, on top of this function, I would need to inform the blocked visitor, that the service is not yet supported in his country.

Is there a way, how to redirect a blocked user to a custom webpage, which would inform the visitor?

I use:

- Ubuntu 14.04 TLS
- NGINX
- PHP, HTML5, MySQL, ...

Thank you for your advice. Kind regards,

Comment: Checking the user's IP address when they initiate a session in the webserver/application (login etc) is another option.

Comment: @Brian, Hi and thanks for the comment. I know it is possible. I have considered this possibility. However, to save server resources it makes sense to block all the *unwanted* visitors as early as possible, which means at the Firewall point. Therefore, i would prefer, if there is a way to redirect blocked users to a webpage.

Comment: In iptables it would be easier to forward their packets to another web server listening on a different port or IP address that just serves the "not available" pages.

Comment: @Brian, hi and that is really great idea indeed. Do you think, that I can have some second and ultralight webserver hosting this only webpage along with nginx, being the main web server? But you have me realy inspiring idea where to start.